# How can I get the values from a Jtable (Java)

Tags: java, jtable, classcastexception

How do I get values for a table example:

#### My Code:

```
Jtable table;
DefaultTableModel model;
Row_Data row = new Row_Data;


row_selected = table.getSelectedRow(); // 
row = (Row_Data)model.getDataVector().elementAt(row_selected)
```

It gives me an error: `ClassCastException`

Comment: include the Full Stack Trace on your post.

Comment: What is `Row_Data`? `DefaultTableModel::getDataVector` returns a `Vector` of `Vector`s.

Comment: "Row_Data" is an Serializable Object that I created

Comment: Show us how you're creating your `TableModel`, and what is the result of `model.getDataVector().elementAt(0).getClass().getName()`?

Comment: `table = new JTable();
model = new DefaultTableModel( new Object[][] {
{null,null,null,null,null,null},
new String[] {
"Tec_Id", "State", "Request_Number", "Description", "Adress", "Dead Line"}
);
table.setModel(model);
table.getColumnModel()...

new Thread(new Hilodisp (table, model, tcp1)).start();`

Comment: There's no `Row_Data` anywhere in there, so why would you think your table model would contain it? Also, you should put that information in your question. Also, you didn't answer the second half of my question. I think you will find it is returning a `Vector` to you.